# How to check if obj1.obj2 exists before accessing a property on obj2

Tags: javascript

Given the variable obj1.obj2.obj3, write a JavaScript snippet to get the value of this variable, which will not cause errors if obj1 or obj2 is undefined.

Comment: `x= typeof obj1 !=='undefined' && obj1.obj2 && obj1.obj2.obj3;`

Answer (score 0):

Most people do `obj1 && obj1.obj2 && obj1.obj2.obj3`

There's lots of other ways to do it though, e.g.

```
var x
try { x = obj1.obj2.obj3 } catch (e) {}
```

which would leave x as undefined

Comment: the first clode block would throw if `obj1` had not been declared.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof obj1 !='undefined'){
    if (typeof obj1.obj2 !='undefined'){
       console.log(obj1.obj2.obj3);
    }
}
```